# R dataframe choosing columns by some part of the name

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with 341 variables. Some of them same type of data for different times. For example for viral load at initiation "t0vload", viral load at 6 moths "t6vload" and goes on. How can I write a command to subset all the columns with a name consisting "-vload"?

Comment: Thank you Akrun, it worked well and I clicked it already but I don't have enough reputation to activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, using `dplyr`, the following should work as well:

```
 select(dat, ends_with("vload"))
```

or:

```
 dat %>% select(ends_with("vload"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grep`

```
 dat[grep("vload$", names(dat))]
```